# FatalException thrown by protobuf library on instantiation of message

Tags: c++, linux, protocol-buffers

I'm compiling protobuf 3.6.1 from source and linking with an executable which is targeted at Ubuntu 16.04. As soon as an object of any message type gets created, the library throws an exception with the following console output:

> [libprotobuf FATAL /myproj/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/generated_message_util.cc:785] CHECK failed: (scc->visit_status.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) == (SCCInfoBase::kRunning):
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'google::protobuf::FatalException'
>   what():  CHECK failed: (scc->visit_status.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) == (SCCInfoBase::kRunning):
>   Aborted

Answer (score 1):

As explained [here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/README.md#c-installation---unix), you need to run `pkg-config` or otherwise determine what build flags to use in a project which uses protobuf. In this particular case, the *pthread* library is missing.

Comment: So what else does one try when all these flags are present for the dependent code? I still get this issue with self-compiled mosh.

Comment: @oarfish, I'm afraid I can't say. It sounds like the topic for a new question.

Comment: In my case i had to compile both client and server with the required flags and also use a recent compiler.